# Distributed Engine DBException

Tags: clickhouse

I have created a table in my local system :
CREATE TABLE default.test_distributed ( a Int8) ENGINE = Distributed(logs, default, test_remote)

and created a table in remote system with IP 10.121.21.33 :
create table test_remote (a Int8) Engine=Log

and then I inserted data in my local system :
insert into test_distributed values (1011)

And then I fired Select query :
select * from test_distributed

And got following exception :
2017.05.02 18:49:36.155606 [ 14 ]  ConnectionPoolWithFailover: Connection failed at try №1, reason: Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
2017.05.02 18:49:36.155982 [ 14 ]  ConnectionPoolWithFailover: Connection failed at try №2, reason: Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
2017.05.02 18:49:36.156316 [ 14 ]  ConnectionPoolWithFailover: Connection failed at try №3, reason: Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
2017.05.02 18:49:36.162780 [ 4 ]  executeQuery: Code: 279, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: All connection tries failed. Log:

Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (10.121.21.33:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException

, e.what() = DB::NetException (from 127.0.0.1:33590) (in query: select * from test_distributed), Stack trace:

1. clickhouse-server(StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x16) [0x17c6e76]
2. clickhouse-server(DB::Exception::Exception(std::string const&, int)+0x1f) [0xfdd9ff]
3. clickhouse-server(PoolWithFailoverBase::getMany(DB::Settings const*, PoolMode)+0x773) [0x17615f3]
4. clickhouse-server(DB::ConnectionPoolWithFailover::doGetMany(DB::Settings const*, PoolMode)+0x33) [0x17617f3]
5. clickhouse-server(DB::MultiplexedConnections::initFromShard(DB::IConnectionPool*)+0x26d) [0x19afcad]
6. clickhouse-server(DB::MultiplexedConnections::MultiplexedConnections(DB::IConnectionPool*, DB::Settings const*, std::shared_ptr, bool, PoolMode)+0x138) [0x19b0a38]
7. clickhouse-server(DB::RemoteBlockInputStream::createMultiplexedConnections()+0x3fb) [0x1665e8b]
8. clickhouse-server(DB::RemoteBlockInputStream::readPrefix()+0x23) [0x166b043]
9. clickhouse-server(DB::AsynchronousBlockInputStream::calculate(MemoryTracker*)+0x60) [0xfe8ea0]
10. clickhouse-server(ThreadPool::worker()+0x141) [0x17d2d91]
11. clickhouse-server() [0x33d4faf]
12. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7f8fe38aa182]
13. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f8fe2ec530d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check settings on local system

```
SELECT * FROM system.clusters
```

and check following files /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml for remote_servers section

see https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#Distributed for remote_servers example config

Comment: I have added cluster "log" in config file under remote_servers 

SELECT *
FROM system.clusters 

┌─cluster─┬─shard_num─┬─shard_weight─┬─replica_num─┬─host_name────┬─host_address─┬─port─┬─is_local─┬─user────┬─default_database─┐
│ logs    │         1 │            1 │           1 │ 10.121.21.33 │ 10.121.21.33 │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
└─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.022 sec.

Comment: try from your local machine?
telnet 10.121.21.33 9000

and check /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml listen option on 10.121.21.33 server

you need
 <listen_host>::</listen_host>
or
 <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>

change it and run 
service clickhouse-server restart

Comment: Actually I have installed ClickHouse on Virtual Machine on Both system.
And I have given Host Name as :
<replica>
                <host>10.121.21.33</host>
                <port>9000</port>
</replica>

Comment: telnet 10.121.21.33 9000
Trying 10.121.21.33...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: check listen_host option on host 10.121.21.33:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml